# MobileVLCKit for iOS fails to build

Tags: ios, vlc, libtool, libtool-xcode

i am following the instructions in https://wiki.videolan.org/VLCKit/ to build a MobileVLCKit.framework for my project. because i have to make minor tweaks to source, i cannot use a ready made build.

i run sudo ./buildMobileVLCKit.sh -vd

and am stuck at

```
The following build commands failed:
        Libtool build/MobileVLCKit.build/Debug-iphoneos/MobileVLCKit.build/Objects-normal/armv7s/libMobileVLCKit.a normal armv7s
        Libtool build/MobileVLCKit.build/Debug-iphoneos/MobileVLCKit.build/Objects-normal/arm64/libMobileVLCKit.a normal arm64
        Libtool build/MobileVLCKit.build/Debug-iphoneos/MobileVLCKit.build/Objects-normal/armv7/libMobileVLCKit.a normal armv7
    (3 failures)
```

more debug info..

```
Libtool build/MobileVLCKit.build/Debug-iphoneos/MobileVLCKit.build/Objects-normal/armv7/libMobileVLCKit.a normal armv7
    cd /Users/me/VLCKit
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=6.1
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/iOSOpenDev/bin:/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin:/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global/bin:/Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin:/Users/me/.rvm/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/libexec/git-core/"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool -static -arch_only armv7 -syslibroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.1.sdk -L/Users/me/VLCKit/build/Debug-iphoneos -filelist /Users/me/VLCKit/build/MobileVLCKit.build/Debug-iphoneos/MobileVLCKit.build/Objects-normal/armv7/MobileVLCKit.LinkFileList -ObjC /Users/me/VLCKit/MobileVLCKit/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/armv7/contribs/lib/libass.a /Users/me/VLCKit/MobileVLCKit/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/armv7/contribs/lib/libavutil.a /Users/me/VLCKit/MobileVLCKit/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/armv7/contribs/lib/libavcodec.a /Users/me/VLCKit/MobileVLCKit/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/armv7/contribs/lib/libavformat.a /Users/me/VLCKit/MobileVLCKit/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/armv7/contribs/lib/libswscale.a /Users/me/VLCKit/MobileVLCKit/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/armv7/contribs/lib/libgsm.a /Users/me/VLCKit/MobileVLCKit/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/armv7/contribs/lib/libdvbpsi.a /Users/me/VLCKit/MobileVLCKit/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/armv7/contribs/lib/libFLAC.a /Users/me/VLCKit/MobileVLCKit/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/armv7/contribs/lib/libfribidi.a /Users/me/VLCKit/MobileVLCKit/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/armv7/contribs/lib/libfreetype.a /Users/me/VLCKit/MobileVLCKit/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/armv7/contribs/lib/libgcrypt.a /Users/me/VLCKit/MobileVLCKit/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/armv7/contribs/lib/libgpg-error.a /Users/me/VLCKit/MobileVLCKit/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/armv7/contribs/lib/libharfbuzz.a /Users/me/VLCKit/MobileVLCKit/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/armv7/contribs/lib/libUsageEnvironment.a /Users/me/VLCKit/MobileVLCKit/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/armv7/contribs/lib/libBasicUsageEnvironment.a /Users/me/VLCKit/MobileVLCKit/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/armv7/contribs/lib/libgroupsock.a /Users/me/VLCKit/MobileVLCKit/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/armv7/contribs/lib/libz.a /Users/me/VLCKit/MobileVLCKit/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/armv7/contribs/lib/libliveMedia.a /Users/me/VLCKit/MobileVLCKit/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/armv7/contribs/lib/libebml.a /Users/me/VLCKit/MobileVLCKit/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/armv7/contribs/lib/libmatroska.a /Users/me/VLCKit/MobileVLCKit/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/armv7/contribs/lib/libmodplug.a /Users/me/VLCKit/MobileVLCKit/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/armv7/contribs/lib/libogg.a /Users/me/VLCKit/MobileVLCKit/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/armv7/contribs/lib/libtheora.a /Users/me/VLCKit/MobileVLCKit/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/armv7/contribs/lib/libtheoradec.a /Users/me/VLCKit/MobileVLCKit/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/armv7/contribs/lib/libtheoraenc.a /Users/me/VLCKit/MobileVLCKit/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/armv7/contribs/lib/libopus.a /Users/me/VLCKit/MobileVLCKit/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/armv7/contribs/lib/libpng.a /Users/me/VLCKit/MobileVLCKit/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/armv7/contribs/lib/libopenjpeg.a /Users/me/VLCKit/MobileVLCKit/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/armv7/contribs/lib/libspeex.a /Users/me/VLCKit/MobileVLCKit/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/armv7/contribs/lib/libspeexdsp.a /Users/me/VLCKit/MobileVLCKit/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/armv7/contribs/lib/libtag.a /Users/me/VLCKit/MobileVLCKit/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/armv7/contribs/lib/libtag_c.a /Users/me/VLCKit/MobileVLCKit/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/armv7/contribs/lib/libxml2.a /Users/me/VLCKit/MobileVLCKit/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/armv7/contribs/lib/libz.a /Users/me/VLCKit/MobileVLCKit/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/armv7/contribs/lib/libzvbi.a /Users/me/VLCKit/MobileVLCKit/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/armv7/lib/vlc/libcompat.a /Users/me/VLCKit/MobileVLCKit/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/armv7/lib/libvlc.a /Users/me/VLCKit/MobileVLCKit/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/armv7/lib/libvlccore.a -framework Foundation -o /Users/me/VLCKit/build/MobileVLCKit.build/Debug-iphoneos/MobileVLCKit.build/Objects-normal/armv7/libMobileVLCKit.a
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: -dynamic not specified the following flags are invalid: -ObjC 
error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: can't open file: /Users/me/VLCKit/MobileVLCKit/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/armv7/contribs/lib/libass.a (No such file or directory)
error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: can't open file: /Users/me/VLCKit/MobileVLCKit/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/armv7/contribs/lib/libavutil.a (No such file or directory)
error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: can't open file: /Users/me/VLCKit/MobileVLCKit/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/armv7/contribs/lib/libavcodec.a (No such file or directory)
error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: can't open file: /Users/me/VLCKit/MobileVLCKit/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/armv7/contribs/lib/libavformat.a (No such file or directory)
error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: can't open file: /Users/me/VLCKit/MobileVLCKit/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/armv7/contribs/lib/libswscale.a (No such file or directory)
error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: can't open file: /Users/me/VLCKit/MobileVLCKit/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/armv7/contribs/lib/libgsm.a (No such file or directory)
error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: can't open file: /Users/me/VLCKit/MobileVLCKit/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/armv7/contribs/lib/libdvbpsi.a (No such file or directory)
error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: can't open file: /Users/me/VLCKit/MobileVLCKit/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/armv7/contribs/lib/libFLAC.a (No such file or directory)
error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: can't open file: /Users/me/VLCKit/MobileVLCKit/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/armv7/contribs/lib/libfribidi.a (No such file or directory)
error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: can't open file: /Users/me/VLCKit/MobileVLCKit/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/armv7/contribs/lib/libfreetype.a (No such file or directory)
error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: can't open file: /Users/me/VLCKit/MobileVLCKit/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/armv7/contribs/lib/libgcrypt.a (No such file or directory)
error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: can't open file: /Users/me/VLCKit/MobileVLCKit/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/armv7/contribs/lib/libgpg-error.a (No such file or directory)
error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: can't open file: /Users/me/VLCKit/MobileVLCKit/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/armv7/contribs/lib/libharfbuzz.a (No such file or directory)
error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: can't open file: /Users/me/VLCKit/MobileVLCKit/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/armv7/contribs/lib/libUsageEnvironment.a (No such file or directory)
error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: can't open file: /Users/me/VLCKit/MobileVLCKit/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/armv7/contribs/lib/libBasicUsageEnvironment.a (No such file or directory)
error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: can't open file: /Users/me/VLCKit/MobileVLCKit/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/armv7/contribs/lib/libgroupsock.a (No such file or directory)
error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: can't open file: /Users/me/VLCKit/MobileVLCKit/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/armv7/contribs/lib/libz.a (No such file or directory)
error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: can't open file: /Users/me/VLCKit/MobileVLCKit/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/armv7/contribs/lib/libliveMedia.a (No such file or directory)
error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: can't open file: /Users/me/VLCKit/MobileVLCKit/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/armv7/contribs/lib/libebml.a (No such file or directory)
error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: can't open file: /Users/me/VLCKit/MobileVLCKit/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/armv7/contribs/lib/libmatroska.a (No such file or directory)
error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: can't open file: /Users/me/VLCKit/MobileVLCKit/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/armv7/contribs/lib/libmodplug.a (No such file or directory)
error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: can't open file: /Users/me/VLCKit/MobileVLCKit/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/armv7/contribs/lib/libogg.a (No such file or directory)
error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: can't open file: /Users/me/VLCKit/MobileVLCKit/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/armv7/contribs/lib/libtheora.a (No such file or directory)
error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: can't open file: /Users/me/VLCKit/MobileVLCKit/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/armv7/contribs/lib/libtheoradec.a (No such file or directory)
error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: can't open file: /Users/me/VLCKit/MobileVLCKit/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/armv7/contribs/lib/libtheoraenc.a (No such file or directory)
error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: can't open file: /Users/me/VLCKit/MobileVLCKit/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/armv7/contribs/lib/libopus.a (No such file or directory)
error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: can't open file: /Users/me/VLCKit/MobileVLCKit/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/armv7/contribs/lib/libpng.a (No such file or directory)
error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: can't open file: /Users/me/VLCKit/MobileVLCKit/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/armv7/contribs/lib/libopenjpeg.a (No such file or directory)
error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: can't open file: /Users/me/VLCKit/MobileVLCKit/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/armv7/contribs/lib/libspeex.a (No such file or directory)
error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: can't open file: /Users/me/VLCKit/MobileVLCKit/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/armv7/contribs/lib/libspeexdsp.a (No such file or directory)
error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: can't open file: /Users/me/VLCKit/MobileVLCKit/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/armv7/contribs/lib/libtag.a (No such file or directory)
error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: can't open file: /Users/me/VLCKit/MobileVLCKit/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/armv7/contribs/lib/libtag_c.a (No such file or directory)
error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: can't open file: /Users/me/VLCKit/MobileVLCKit/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/armv7/contribs/lib/libxml2.a (No such file or directory)
error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: can't open file: /Users/me/VLCKit/MobileVLCKit/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/armv7/contribs/lib/libz.a (No such file or directory)
error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: can't open file: /Users/me/VLCKit/MobileVLCKit/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/armv7/contribs/lib/libzvbi.a (No such file or directory)
error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: can't open file: /Users/me/VLCKit/MobileVLCKit/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/armv7/lib/vlc/libcompat.a (No such file or directory)
error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: can't open file: /Users/me/VLCKit/MobileVLCKit/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/armv7/lib/libvlc.a (No such file or directory)
error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: can't open file: /Users/me/VLCKit/MobileVLCKit/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/armv7/lib/libvlccore.a (No such file or directory)
```

an inspection confirms that i do not have this directory at all VLCKit/MobileVLCKit/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS

why?

my environment: mavericks, xcode 5.1, ios SDK 7.1

Comment: Your compilation failed at some point way prior to those messages. Precisely, libvlc was never created. Re-run the compilation script with -v, post the log and I can see what I can do.

Comment: Oh, and next time, it might be a good idea to post those issues on our forums directly, to get a faster response :)